# Golly game of life in a gif

Tags: animated-gif, conways-game-of-life

I have a talk in a few days. I have to make a reference to the cellular atomata. I would like to show a little gif in the slideshow where the evolution of cellular automata is shown, so my question is:How can I convert a pattern and the evolution created with golly game of life to a animated gif?

Answer (score 6):

Golly 2.3 on ubuntu shipped with a nice Perl script especially for making gifs. You can access scripts by hitting the show/hide scripts button on the left panel. The script is called "giffer" and you use it by simply making a selection, starting the script, and then filling in the requested parameters.

BAM! giffed.

Answer (score -2):

You can take multiple screenshots of the animation, then import it as a sequence into After Effects, and export as animated gif.